# Auto suggest Implementation in sencha

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch

can you please tell me how to implement auto suggest in sencha .I googled it and found two or three solution .But all  solution auto suggest using web service ,But i have array of data ,from this data(example names ) i want to use this array in autosuggest .can you modified this link so as i can use this.

i found these links

https://github.com/martintajur/sencha-touch-2-autocomplete-textfield

Answer (score 0):

take a look at this example "Custom Search Fields "
http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.0/examples/form/forum-search.html

Comment: hello thanks ..But this example is same as i give ..i need simple example without using of websersive,

Answer (score 0):

[`TypeAhead`](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.form.field.ComboBox-cfg-typeAhead) is build-in ExtJS combobox. You can hide the trigger and it will look like a textbox with autosuggest.
Look at [this page](http://skirtlesden.com/articles/extjs-comboboxes-part-1) for a good tutorial on how to customize your combobox.

Comment: <script type="text/javascript"> 
 
    Ext.application({
   

        launch: function () {
  console.log("Naveen");
         Ext.create('Ext.form.field.ComboBox', { 
       store: ['Red', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Brown', 'Blue', 'Pink', 'Black'] 
       }); 
}
      });

</script>

Comment: Sencha Touch doesn't have ComboBox component

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at my blog, it may be helpful to you. [Sencha touch 2 auto complete.](http://novasys.in/blogs/2013/09/05/setting-up-autocompletion-in-sencha-touch-2-with-sublimetext-2/)